# How to resolve Magento 2 dependencies while installing extension?

Tags: magento2, extensions, conflict

Magento 2.4.3-p1

I am trying to install an extension using this command:

```
composer require dhl/shipping-m2
```

I am getting this conflict:

```
Problem 1
    - symfony/deprecation-contracts v3.0.0 requires php >=8.0.2 ->
your PHP version (7.4.28) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/deprecation-contracts v3.0.0 requires php >=8.0.2 ->
your PHP version (7.4.28) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/deprecation-contracts v3.0.0 requires php >=8.0.2 ->
your PHP version (7.4.28) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for symfony/deprecation-contracts (locked
at v3.0.0) -> satisfiable by symfony/deprecation-contracts[v3.0.0].
```

When I run composer with PHP 8 , I am getting:

```
Problem 1
    - amzn/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin 5.9.1 requires php
~7.0.13||~7.1.0||~7.2.0||~7.3.0||~7.4.0 -> your PHP version (8.0.14)
does not satisfy that requirement.
    - amzn/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin 5.9.1 requires php
~7.0.13||~7.1.0||~7.2.0||~7.3.0||~7.4.0 -> your PHP version (8.0.14)
does not satisfy that requirement.
    - amzn/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin 5.9.1 requires php
~7.0.13||~7.1.0||~7.2.0||~7.3.0||~7.4.0 -> your PHP version (8.0.14)
does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for amzn/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin
5.9.1 -> satisfiable by amzn/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin[5.9.1]
```

How would I resolve this? The PHP version I want to use is 7.4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Solved it myself by adding the `--ignore-platform-reqs` to my command!

```
composer require dhl/shipping-m2 --ignore-platform-reqs
```